# nhibernate to linq 3.2 generate error sql on || operator

Tags: linq, nhibernate, orm

now i'm using nhibernate 3.2 as the orm,when i write code like this:

```
PostReaderBll postReaderBll=new PostReaderBll();
    var query = from p in postReaderBll.Query()
                where (p.Post.Flag == (int)PostType.Post && p.Post.MailState == (int)MailState.Normal) || (p.ReceiveUser == LoginUser.UserIdentity && p.Post.Flag == (int)PostType.Mail && p.Post.MailState == (int)APSP.Form.MailState.Normal)
                select p;
```

i get this sql:

```
SELECT   TOP ( 10 /* @p0 */ ) ID1_70_,
                 IsRead2_70_,
                 ReceiveU3_70_,
                 ReadDate4_70_,
                 Flag5_70_,
                 Label6_70_,
                 PostID7_70_   FROM     (select postreader0_.[ID]     as ID1_70_,
             postreader0_.[IsRead]              as IsRead2_70_,
             postreader0_.[ReceiveUser]         as ReceiveU3_70_,
             postreader0_.[ReadDate]            as ReadDate4_70_,
             postreader0_.[Flag]                as Flag5_70_,
             postreader0_.[Label]               as Label6_70_,
             postreader0_.[PostID]              as PostID7_70_,      ROW_NUMBER()
               OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row
      from   PostReader postreader0_
             inner join Post post1_
               on postreader0_.[PostID] = post1_.[ID]
      where  post1_.[Flag] = 1 /* @p1 */
             and post1_.[MailState] = 0 /* @p2 */
              or postreader0_.[ReceiveUser] = 'admin' /* @p3 */
                 and post1_.[Flag] = 0 /* @p4 */
                 and post1_.[MailState] = 0 /* @p5 */) as query   WHERE   query.__hibernate_sort_row > 0 /* @p6 */  ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

but i need the where  like this:

```
( post1_.[Flag] = 1 /* @p1 */
             and post1_.[MailState] = 0 /* @p2 */)
              or (postreader0_.[ReceiveUser] = 'admin' /* @p3 */
                 and post1_.[Flag] = 0 /* @p4 */
                 and post1_.[MailState] = 0 /* @p5 */)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same because, OR operators are always evaluated after AND operators.

Reference documentation for OR operator:

> Combines two conditions. When more than one logical operator is used
>   in a statement, **OR operators are evaluated after AND operators**.
>   However, you can change the order of evaluation by using parentheses.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx